# change label name for a products attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress site, and under other information for a single WooCommerce product it shows shipping size. Does anyone know how to hide or change the label name? 
I think it is this label `th.woocommerce-product-attributes-label-item_label`.

I have tried to look under products, but can't find the attribute as it is generated from 3 different attributes.